# How can I get the mediaqueries I wrote on my CSS to work on my Wordpress site when I see it on a phone/tablet?

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, media-queries

I was testing this site that I just developed on wordpress: [circoloshowroom.com](http://www.circoloshowroom.com)
and I added all the proper media queries in order for it to be responsive. Now, when I resize the browser window my media queries work fine. However, when I look at the site on my phone or tablet it shows the site fully and the media queries get ignored. Any suggestions? Is it something Wordpress does to my site from the beginning. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this by adding this to the top of header.php file

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
```

FYI: By default, iPhone Safari shrinks HTML pages to fit into the iPhone screen. The following meta tag tells iPhone Safari to use the width of the device as the width of the viewport and disable the initial scale.
Somethis I just learned from this super helpful blog post: [webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries)